# Nodes in PGFPlots Get Cut Off

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes

I'm trying to draw a basic graph in `pgfplots` but facing an issue that I wasn't able to solve based on similar posts. I'm trying to add the functions I'm displaying on my graph on their respective lines using nodes, but I end up getting the following result:

```tex
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=center,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    xmin=-1,
    xmax=1.5,
    ymin=-1,
    ymax=2.5,
    xtick distance=1,
    clip=true,]
    \addplot[name path=A, thick, black, samples=200]{x} node[pos=0.61, right]{$y=x$};
    \addplot[name path=B, thick, black, samples=200]{x + 1} node[pos=0.61, right]{$y=x + 1$};
    \addplot[fill=red]fill between[of=A and B, soft clip={domain=0:1}];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

As you can see from the image, `y = x _+ 1` gets cut off, while `y = x` is just at the edge of it, barely saving it. I tried setting `clip=false` but my graph goes haywire, getting displaced from the center and going all over my page:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: in the `\addplot` command, you can specify the x domain, something like `domain=--1:1.5`....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the domain to the functions

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=center,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    xmin=-1,
    xmax=2,
    ymin=-1,
    ymax=2.5,
    xtick distance=1]
    \addplot[name path=A, thick, black, samples=20, domain=-1:2]{x} node[pos=0.61, right]{$y=x$};
    \addplot[name path=B, thick, black, samples=20, domain=-1:2]{x + 1} node[pos=0.61, right]{$y=x + 1$};
    \addplot[fill=red]fill between[of=A and B, soft clip={domain=0:1}];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Cheers mate! Made a somewhat decent looking graph thanks to this. Appreciated!